# AWS ELB/ALB Multiple SSL Certicifates

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl

I'm looking for a way to use multiple ssl certificates (over 100) on a single AWS ELB/ALB - how can I implement that?

Comment: Even better, just use a single certificate.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this.  Not directly.

ELB Classic supports 1 cert per listener and of course only one listener on port 443.

ALB [supports 26 certificates](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-application-load-balancer-sni/) (25 plus the default, which is used whenever the incoming SNI is unmatched or absent).

But, certificates can support multiple domains, so that's one way of getting support for more than 25 (+1) domains -- combine the domains onto a smaller number of certs.  <strike>This is a limit that cannot be increased.</strike> You can request an [increase for the quota](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-limits.html) that limits the number of certs on a balancer, though I don't have official knowledge of the upper boundary.  One comment, below, suggests that it can be increased to 100.

[image: Quote increased to 100]

Or, create one CloudFront distribution per certificate, pointing them to the ALB as origin server.  This allows you to support as many certs as you want with the services deployed behind one balancer, up to the limits for distributions on your account.  The [default limit is 200](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-limits.html#limits-web-distributions) CloudFront distributions in each account, but this can be increased by request.  This can also be used to potentially reduce the load on the instances behind the balancer, since CloudFront can be configured to cache responses.

Comment: I just read this:
http://rrsoft.co/2016/07/11/using-lets-encrypt-for-a-multi-tenant-web-application/

Which is great, the thing is that i have 10 nginx services behind a load balancer, should I place the cert files + configs on each one of them? doesnt makes sense

Comment: That article pre-dates the availability of Network Load Balancer, which would be a better solution than ELB... but, yes, you'd need the certs on all of your instances with such a setup.  You could use HAProxy in front of Nginx and then probably only need 2 instances.  There are a lot of solutions, here.  Amazon Certificate Manager has multi-domain ("SAN") certificates that work with ALB (as I alluded to, above, *"certificates can support multiple domains"*).  And then there's CloudFlare (not part of AWS, but works with ELB/ALB/NLB/EC2), which has essentially zero-config automatic SSL.

Comment: Where do I place the proxies (HAproxy)? i'm confused

Comment: ALB supports 100 with a quota change request https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-limits.html

Comment: @rjdkolb thanks, updated.  Do you have a citation for the upper limit on the quota of 100?

Comment: I can't find any documentation..., but I added a picture of the new quota we have. (I was not sure how to send it to you, feel free to edit/delete)